# How to avoid error message: reference to "is_empty" is ambiguous

Tags: c++, eclipse, boost, is-empty, ambiguous

So in my code, I've used a method is_empty()in the boost library. I know `is_empty` has two definitions, one is in the filesystem library of boost:
`std::filesystem:is_empty(const std::filesystem::path& p)`.
And another is in std::integral_constant:
`inline constexpr bool is_empty_v = is_empty<T>::value`;
I intended to use the one that is in the boost library, but how can I do it? I tried to not do `using namespace std` at the beginning. Instead, every time I need to `cout`, I'd use `std::cout` to avoid the possible ambiguous on my `is_empty` method. But I still got the same error if I do this. Is there any other way that can resolve this misconception? I attached part of my code snippet below. Thank you!

```
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"
#include "boost/filesystem.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
...
using namespace boost::filesystem;
using namespace cv;
    ... inside main() function:
    ...
    directory_iterator itr(param.referFolder);
    if( is_empty(itr->path()) )
    {
        std::cout << "ERROR: ReferenceFolder is empty. Please place reference images inside." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    ... ...
    for(directory_iterator itr(param.dataFolder); itr != end_itr; ++itr) // search every folder
    {
        if(is_directory(itr->status()) && !is_empty(itr->path())){
            ... ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: Stop importing entire namespaces into your project at a global level. explicitly specify the one you want using scope resolution operators.

Comment: "_But I still got the same error if I do this._": Please show a proper [mre] including the error so that we can copy-paste it and try to compile it ourselves.

Comment: Change `is_empty` to `boost::filesystem::is_empty`.

Comment: Or, at least use namespace aliases, eg: `namespace fs = boost::filesystem;` and then you can qualify things like `fs::directory_iterator`, `fs::is_empty()`, `fs::is_directory()`, etc.